# Android EditText throws NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have been trying many thing but still dont know what is going on, 
i want to input url adress into editText and then saveit into String or set this text to TextView after user click button

then i get

Halp

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a
>   null object reference

```
Button button1;
    TextView txtspr;
     EditText   urlInputEditText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

                txtspr=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSprawdzajacy);
                urlInputEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

                //(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            }
        });
    }

   public void onClick(View view) {

            String n=urlInputEditText.getText().toString();
            txtspr.setText(n);


        //new DownloadAsync(this,n).execute();

    }
```

Comment: can we have the resources where you have set the text for `editText` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:** 
you are clicking on `button1` but it is not yet initialized (the init. was inside of the `FloatingActionButton` )

**Solution**
try this code:

```
Button button1;
TextView txtspr;
EditText   urlInputEditText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            txtspr=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSprawdzajacy);
            urlInputEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View view) {
        String n=urlInputEditText.getText().toString();
        txtspr.setText(n);
}
```

Comment: ok i'm fkn blind :D i have noticced that :P i need a break :D thx

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to assign any value to the `urlInputEditText` from your resources.

Since this section would only be called `onClick()` according to your code :

```
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ....
                button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         urlInputEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Move the assignment out of the click somewhere in `onCreate()`